# do.call argument "geneList" is missing, with no default when using gseGO

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, do.call

I'm working on a highly configurable R script. I have made a function in witch there are several more functions, like gseGO from **clusterProfiler package**.

To be configurable by the user I would like to call this function by do.call(gseGO, parameter_list). Where parameter_list is a list of all the parameters the user will provide.

My problem is, that when I try a test run for do.call, I got an error. My code looks like this:

```
gse <- do.call(gseGO, c(geneList=cluster_data[[1]],
              ont ="BP",
              keyType = "ENTREZID",
              nPerm = 10000,
              minGSSize = 3,
              maxGSSize = 800,
              pvalueCutoff = 1,
              verbose = TRUE,
              OrgDb = config$organism_org,
              pAdjustMethod = config$pAdjustMethod))
```

and the error is: `argument "geneList" is missing, with no default`

But when I run this same code without do.call like this:

```
gse_bp <- gseGO(geneList=cluster_data[[1]],
              ont ="BP",
              keyType = "ENTREZID",
              nPerm = 10000,
              minGSSize = 3,
              maxGSSize = 800,
              pvalueCutoff = 1,
              verbose = TRUE,
              OrgDb = config$organism_org,
              pAdjustMethod = config$pAdjustMethod)
```

It runs as it supposed to be with no problem.

And for the final code I would like something to look like this:

```
gse_bp <- do.call(gseGO, c(geneList=cluster_data[[1]],
              ont ="BP",
              keyType = "ENTREZID",
              OrgDb = config$organism_org,
              pAdjustMethod = config$pAdjustMethod,
              parameter_list))
```

What could be the problem? Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Cross-posted : https://www.biostars.org/p/9545851/

Comment: The second argument of `do.call` must be a list. Try replacing `c` with `list`.

Comment: @Roland Yes that will work!